# A table has following fields

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID    Datetime    Price 
1     25Jan       10
1     26Jan       11
2     23JAN       12
2     24JAN       13
```

I want the following result

```
ID    Datetime    (Daytime-1)    (PRice for today)    (LastDayprice)
1     26 JAN      25 JAN         11                   10
2     24JAN       23 JAN         13                   12
```

Any help regarding SQL will be appreciated!

Comment: If you some more rows of sample data and adjust the expected result accordingly, it will be easier for us to understand the problem.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: And there are never to prices for the same day?

Comment: I have added some more rows of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.ID,t.Datetime,s.datetime as yesterday,t.price,s.price as yest_price
FROM YourTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable s
ON t.id = s.id and t.datetime = s.datetime+1
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is working.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d90e/13)**</kbd>

```
SELECT prv.id, 
       cur.datetime, 
       prv.datetime AS "Daytime-1", 
       cur.price    AS "PRice for today", 
       prv.price    AS LastDayprice 
FROM   table1 prv 
       left join (SELECT id, 
                         datetime, 
                         price 
                  FROM   table1) cur 
              ON prv.id = cur.id 
                 AND prv.datetime = Date_sub(cur.datetime, interval 1 day) 
WHERE  cur.id IS NOT NULL
```